# MacBook keeps showing question mark on startup

Tags: snow-leopard

I am using MacBook 2010 with OS X 10.6.8. Today when I started my laptop it kept showing the Apple logo longer than expected. Then I read online to hold the shift key while booting. Doing that it started showing a folder icon with a question mark and it keeps showing untill the laptop gets shut down. Right now I don't have any disk utility tool either.

How do I solve my problem?

Comment: [A flashing question mark or globe appears when you start your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204323)

Comment: @Volatil3 You promised to make a backup and create a recovery thumb drive after the almost  fatal `rm *` incident ;-). Did you already try to reset PRAM and SMC?

Comment: @klanomath I did have data backup ready but definitely not all installation and command line tools I had configured. I tried to run `fschk` but it failed to recover. I rather then got a new HD and installed Yosemite and trying to setup everything from scratch :(. The OLD HD can only be used as a data storage.

Comment: @Volatil3 So did you buy a new HDD already?

Comment: @klanomath yeah

Comment: @Volatil3 Hmm somehow your question is unclear to me: Did you already replace the internal disk? Is Yosemite installed on the new one?

Comment: @klanomath Yes I gotrid of old one and installed Yosemite on newer one.

Comment: @Volatil3 And you get the "no boot disk found" sign after installing Yosemite? Your question is tagged with Snow Leopard, which is confusing then.

Comment: @klanomath All those issues were on old HD. I believe it could be solved by formatting it too but media of it was already weak so I preferred to get a new one

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your hard disk could be on its way out.

A folder icon with a question mark means that the Mac can not find a valid Operating System on the disk (or the OS which was on there has become corrupted).

Booting with your finger on shift boots the Mac into, what is called, *Safe Mode* (or *Safe Boot*). That is to say no extra software is loaded at boot time, only the essentials, as well as some checks being performed. Quoting the [Apple web site for Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-is/HT201262):

> Starting up in Safe Mode does several things:
>
> - It verifies your startup disk, and attempts to repair directory    issues if needed.
> - Only required kernel extensions are loaded.
> - All user installed fonts are disabled while you are in Safe Mode.
> - Startup Items and Login Items are not opened during startup and login    on OS X v10.4 or later.
> - In OS X 10.4 and later, font caches that are stored in    /Library/Caches/com.apple.ATS/uid/ are moved to the Trash (where uid
>     is a user ID number).
> - In OS X v10.3.9 or earlier, Safe Mode opens only Apple-installed    startup items. These items are usually located in
>     /Library/StartupItems. These items are different from user-selected
>     account login items.
>
> Together, these changes can help resolve or isolate certain issues on
>   your startup disk.

Your best bet is to start your Mac using an install OS X CD (or USB stick) or an external disk drive containing another installation of Mac OS X, and run Disk Utility (or preferably Disk Doctor) from that and/or reinstall the OS. Better still, maybe seriously consider replacing the hard disk, if it is getting old, and failing.

Also, it maybe worth copying off any data that you require (or do not  wish to lose).  However, saying that, you can always use your [time machine] backup to recover any lost files. You have been making regular backups, haven't you?

Comment: Repair Utility failed again and again and I rather bought a new HD

Comment: What are the errors that Repair Utility is reporting? Can you update your original question with a screen shot of the error? Thanks. Also, how old is your hard disk?

Comment: I don't remember exact anymore but it's said something like `can not repair this hardisk or volume, backup file etc as soon as possible`

Comment: If you could run the test again, and get a photo, or screenshot, that would be great for two reasons. Firstly, the more accurate the information you provide in your question, the more accurate our answers can be. Secondly, your additional information will, undoubtedly, help someone else who has the same problem and finds your question on the internet. Thanks again.